# Is there a way to add a specific Role to when connecting to an Oracle DB via JBDC

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to use Java to connect to an Oracle DB with ASM. I want to query ASM specific metrics. However, I can only access it with the `"sysasm"` role.

Here are a couple of examples of my URLs:

```
connectionUrl: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*host*)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=+ASM)(INSTANCE_NAME=+ASM1)(UR=A)))"

connectionUrl: "jdbc:oracle:thin:\"sys/*password* as sysasm\"@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=+ASM)(INSTANCE_NAME=+ASM1)(UR=A)))"

connectionUrl: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@*host*:1521:+ASM1"
```

I took a look in the docs but I couldn't see anything about roles and the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

The "as sysasm" should be applied to the user:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:\"sys as sysasm/*password*\"@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=+ASM)(INSTANCE_NAME=+ASM1)(UR=A)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void connect() throws Exception {
        String connectString;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        connectString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*host*)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=+ASM)(INSTANCE_NAME=+ASM1)(UR=A)))"

        System.out.println("Before DriverManager.getConnection");
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, "sys as sysasm", "password_for_sys");
            System.out.println("Connection established");

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Exception inside connect(): " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```